# How to use appscript to merge cells based on certain condition?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this sample sheet. There are three columns with data in this sheet. Now, my questions are-

1. How do I merge the cells on *column D*, i.e. `Source`, if the corresponding cells in *column C*, i.e. `Category` have same value?
2. Apply border to separate, whenever the values in `Category` column changes ?

I want to achieve the both of the above using appscript?

[image]

[Link to the sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f0WTDJeGcwIHV7s6KQzdY6DbaHYHjKgwjLJbsqqm_p4/edit#gid=2100307022) (if needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When column "C" is edited, you want to merge column "D" by the values of column "C".

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and please set your sheet name and save the script. When you use this script, please edit the column "C" of the sheet. By this, the script is automatically run.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sample"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != 3 || range.rowStart == 1) return;
  const r = sheet.getRange("C2:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  r.offset(0, 1).breakApart();
  const obj = sheet.getRange("C2:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((o, [c], i) => (o[c] = o[c] ? [...o[c], i + 2] : [i + 2], o), {});
  const ranges = Object.values(obj).map(e => `D${e[0]}:D${e[e.length - 1]}`);
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).getRanges().forEach(r => r.merge());
}
```

#### Testing:

When column "C" is edited, this script is run and the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [breakApart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#breakapart)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [merge()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#merge)